use-package :bind loads package when passed symbol but not variable
I'm using the built in use-package macro of GNU Emacs 29.4.
When I do
(use-package magit
    :bind ("C-x g" . magit))

magit does not get loaded on emacs startup, as expected. But when I use the 'magit symbol like:
(use-package magit
    :bind ("C-x g" . 'magit))

magit is loaded on startup.
And what I find even weirder is that when using:
(use-package magit
    :commands 'magit)

it doesn't get loaded at startup again.
Why does using :bind with a symbol not defer the loading, when using :bind with a variable or :commands with either a symbol or variable does defer the loading?

This also happens when loading other packages.
I use: GNU Emacs 29.4 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.42, cairo version 1.18.0)

As per 3.2 Deferring package loading of the manual (M-: (info "(use-package) Deferring loading")):

Some ‘use-package’ keywords provide autoload “triggers” that cause
a package to be loaded when certain events occur.  For example, the
‘:hook’ keyword sets up a trigger that fires when the specified hook
is run, and then loads the package automatically.  The other trigger
keywords, all of which are described later in this manual, are
‘:commands’, ‘:bind’, ‘:bind*’, ‘:bind-keymap’, ‘:bind-keymap*’,
‘:mode’, and ‘:interpreter’.

Also, 4.2.1 Global keybindings (M-: (info "(use-package) Global keybindings")) says:

Here is an example of using a single cons:
 (use-package ace-jump-mode
   :bind ("C-." . ace-jump-mode))

This does two things: first, it creates an autoload for the
‘ace-jump-mode’ command and defers loading of the ‘ace-jump-mode’
package until you actually use it.  Second, it binds the key ‘C-.’ to
that command globally.

So basically, :bind and :commands defers the loading of the package and nowhere in the manual I see them used with a quoted symbol.

thank you very much for taking the time, but this doesn't really answer my question. I already wrote that using :bind with a variable defers the loading, so the example code doesn't really add anything, since it is the same as the code I provided. I have clarified my question in an update

My point is that, if I read the manual well, the deferring mechanism works as long as you do not use a quoted symbol, simply because using a quoted symbol is not documented. But I could have make it clearer, and I think @db48x makes it clearer by pointing you at the actual code.

It is not possible to pass variables to use-package. It’s a macro, so its arguments are not evaluated. This means that you never need to quote anything you put in a use-package form. If you do, use-package will see something you don’t expect.
This:
(use-package magit
    :bind ("C-x g" . 'magit))

is equivalent to this:
(use-package magit
    :bind ("C-x g" . (quote magit)))

It is hard to say, without reading the code, what use-package will actually autoload in that case. Hopefully nothing, but possibly something you didn’t expect.
